# Preventing Flex application caching in browser (multiple modules)

Tags: apache-flex, caching

I have a Flex application with multiple modules.

When I redeploy the application I was finding that modules (which are deployed as separate swf files) were being cached in the browser and the new versions weren't being loaded.

So i tried the age old trick of adding `?version=xxx` to all the modules when they are loaded. The value `xxx` is a global parameter which is actually stored in the host html page:

```
var moduleSection:ModuleLoaderSection;
moduleSection = new ModuleLoaderSection();
moduleSection.visible = false;
moduleSection.moduleName = moduleName + "?version=" + MySite.masterVersion;
```

In addition I needed to add `?version=xxx` to the main .swf that was being loaded. Since this is done by HTML I had to do this by modifying my AC_OETags.js file as below :

```
function AC_FL_RunContent(){
  var ret = 
    AC_GetArgs
    (  arguments, ".swf?mv=" + getMasterVersion(), "movie", "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
     , "application/x-shockwave-flash"
    );
  AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs);
}
```

This is all fine and works great. I just have a hard time believing that Adobe doesn't already have a way to handle this. Given that Flex is being targeted to design modular applications for business I find it especially surprising.

What do other people do? I need to make sure my application reloads correctly even if someone has `once per session` selected for their 'browser cache checking policy'.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and ended up putting the SWF files in a sub-directory named as the build number. This meant that the URL to the SWF files pointed to a different location each time.

Ideally this should be catered for by the platform, but no joy there. But this works perfectly for us, and integrates very easily into our automated builds with Hudson - no complaints so far.

Answer (score 2):

Flex says:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001388.html

Comment: this is specifically intended for performance testing where you NEVER want anything cached. the question is specifically related to over optimistically caching when you don't want it cached. but definitely useful when testing - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is checksum the SWF file and then add that to its url. Stays the same until the file is rebuilt/redeployed. Handled automagically by a few lines of server-side PHP script

Comment: sounds interesting. i like the 'set and forget' thinking. where are you storing/caching these checksums? you're not recalculating them automagically with every page request are you?

Comment: In my application the page holding the SWF is loaded once (or verrry infrequently - i do ajax & flex remoting after that). And so calculating the md5 checksum in PHP while assembling the page is not a big deal. My SWF is less than 120K in size so this work is done pretty fast. ...

Comment: .. for the much larger resource SWFs that I also use, I put the computed checksum into a side-file that is written at creation-time. Ajax responses convey checksum-tagged SWF urls to client as needed.

Answer (score 1):

here is sample.

```
  function AC_FL_RunContent(){
    var ret = AC_GetArgs(arguments, ".swf?ts=" + getTS(), "movie", 
              "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000",
              "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs);  
  }

  function getTS() {
    var ts = new Date().getTime();
    return ts;
  }
```

AC_OETags.js is file and it exists html-template several places. 
but as my posting said, I am facing another type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The caching is not done by Flash Player but by the browser, so it's out of Adobe's control. I think you have found a workable solution. If I want to avoid caching I usually append a random number on the URL.

Comment: right, but finding a workable solution isnt out of their control. primarily i want to make sure i'm not missing some built in feature and reinventing the wheel. i specifically DONT want a random number because I want the application to be cached when possible