# Flex: Ensure that users get newest version not cached version?

Tags: apache-flex, caching

Is there a way to ensure that when a user views my Flex app, that they are using the newest version and not a cached one?

**A duplicate of this post -- [preventing-flex-application-caching ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300757/preventing-flex-application-caching-in-browser-multiple-modules).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a server-side scripting language, take the content of the HTML wrapper, put it into a script file and add something random to the end of the SWF's URL:

content/application.swf?1234567890

Appending the current time in milliseconds usually works well.

Comment: But I am using AC_FL_RunContent("src", "MothersRings", ...); which doesn't say the extension, so how can I add ?123 after the extension? Get what I mean?

Comment: You could update the Javascript function in AC_OETags.js to append the randomized bit to the query string. None of the functions in that file are super complicated.